# Can I edit in embedded view of Excel in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, page-layout, excel, view

I have a section of Excel spreadsheet that is embedded in a sharepoint 2013 page. For example: Weekly Duty Roster.

I want the end user to be able to click in the embedded viewable cells, edit content, and save so that the file itself gets updated. Is it possible?

So far my different approaches have not worked. I had to redirect them to open the file on Excel actual either on browser or on their machines and then update as usual.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible in a way.  I assume that you will use the excel web part to view the spreadsheet.  Your users will need to click on open in excel, complete their changes, and save.  Once the page is refreshed the updates should be reflected there.

Comment: I thought so. However, I was hoping for a way to avoid having the users open the file in excel. The problem there is that it requires them to have excel installed and more importantly, once its open, other users cant update simultaneously on web. I am exploring if an alternative to it exists.

Comment: You could also configure Microsoft Office web apps:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx